Closed form partition and strict partition function questions
I have made progress on closed-form equations for the partition and strict partition functions. I have discovered a simple closed-form equation for strict partitions of n for triplets. How do I get my work reviewed and potentially published? I see a potential pattern that can be potentially exploited using modular math and would love some help to see if I am on the right track. Thank you!

You could look for a mathematician or for a mathematics journal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematics_journals https://ems.press/journals
